# How can I load an image using Python Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I load an image this way:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.png')
```

gives me the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.png'
```

I have saved the image 'test.png' on the desktop.

So where should I save the image?

Comment: Are you running the script from the desktop aswell? The image should be in the same directory as the script and you should run the script from that directory.

Comment: Try using the full path to the file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to give the directory where the file is located. So if you put in desktop it should go something like this:

```
Image.open('C:\Users\$(your_user_name)\Desktop\test.png')
```

or move the file "test.png" to folder where your script is.